# perl -pe one liner: Replace all matched characters with same number of a different character. Not global

Tags: perl, regex, sed

I'm wondering if there is a Perl (or other) one-liner which will replace all hyphens `-` with *the same number of* circumflexes `^`, provided the hyphens start at the beginning of the line.

Example input:

```
Title 1
-------
Title two
---------
   +--------+
   |asciibox|
   +--------+
```

for which the output should be:

```
Title 1
^^^^^^^
Title two
^^^^^^^^^
   +--------+
   |asciibox|
   +--------+
```

In Perl itself I could run something like this:

```
s!(-+)!"^" x length($1)!e;
```

But is there a way to do this from command line?

Comment: `perl -pe 's!!!e' in.txt > out.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have all the ingredients in your question. Your subject line asks for `perl -pe` and you have written a working substitution, so you simply need to combine the two

I'm not sure what your `\b` is for; you need `^` to anchor the start of a line. And it's probably best to stick with the usual slash delimiters if anyone else is reading your code. But all you need to do is wrap your substitution in quotes like this

```
perl -pe 's/^(-+)/"^" x length($1)/e' myfile.txt
```

#### output

```
Title 1
^^^^^^^
Title two
^^^^^^^^^
   +--------+
   |asciibox|
   +--------+
```

Comment: Ahh, damn! I tried exactly that but missed the /e on the end and ended up having the literal text "^" x length... printed out. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Yes, with the `\G` anchor that matches the start of a string or the position after the previous match:

```
perl -pe 's/\G-/^/g'
```

---

An other way you can use with either Perl or sed: a test and a translation

```
perl -pe 'y/-/^/ if /^-+$/'
```

or

```
sed '/^--*$/y/-/^/'
```

Comment: The first one is awesome! I often wondered what `\G` is good for in practice, now you gave a nice example. Thanks.

Comment: @PerlDog: Thanks. The main interest of this anchor is to ensure contiguous results when you perform a global research. It isn't always easy to use because most of the time you need a first match that is not at the start of the line (in this case the pattern becomes more complicated), but here all the conditions are fulfilled for use it easily.

Answer (score 1):

More or less for fun, two (more) solutions avoiding `/e`:

```
perl -pe '1 while s/^-*\K-/^/'
```

Repeatedly replace the last in a series of dashes beginning at the beginning of the line with a caret. Prior to perl 5.10, `1 while s/^(-*)-/$1^/` can be used instead.

```
perl -pe '$_=reverse; s/-(?=-*$)/^/g; $_=reverse'
```

First, reverse the line front-to-back. Then, repeatedly replace any dash which has nothing but other dashes between it and the end of the line with a caret. Finally, put the line back in the right order. The two `reverse`s allow a single replacement, since `s///g` operates left-to-right and variable-length lookahead is allowed, but the mirror-image statements aren't true.